# Custom Event not firing

Tags: vba, excel

I am in Excel 2010 and I seem to be getting a strange rather unexpected behaviour working with custom events.

*I am like 99% sure this approach has worked for me a few years ago (maybe it was in Excel 03/07 - can't remember)* **or** *maybe I've just messed something up*...

Here's a repro:

Add a new class module and name it `Factory`

```
Public Event AfterInitialize()

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    RaiseEvent AfterInitialize
End Sub
```

Add another class module and name is `FactoryTest`

```
Private WithEvents cFactory As Factory

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set cFactory = New Factory
End Sub

Private Sub cFactory_AfterInitialize()
    Debug.Print "after inialized..."
End Sub
```

and a standard `Module1` and run the below

```
Sub Main()

    Dim fTest As FactoryTest
    Set fTest = New FactoryTest

End Sub
```

At this point I expected to see `after initialized..` in the Immediate Window but I don't...

Stepping-through the code it seems that the `Private Sub cFactory_AfterInitialize()` is never reached...

Note:

I can add a public sub: `RaiseAfterInitialize()` to the `Factory` class and then call that explicitly in the `Initialize()` event in the `FactoryTest` like `cFactory.RaiseAfterInitialize()` so that could be a possible work around but what I am really trying to understand is why it doesn't work the original way showed above?

[There isn't much on VBA events on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278940(v=office.14).aspx)

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it simply be `Factory_AfterInitialize()`?

Comment: I suspect it's timing. The Factory class hasn't finished initializing so the event is raised before the variable in the FactoryTest class is assigned or sinking events.

Comment: In all other places in VBA the events are called based on the Class and not the Class object.  For Example: `Workbook_Open()` not `ThisWorkbook_Open`.

Comment: @jbarker2160 they are different type of events. Built-in events are different from Custom events.

Comment: And you're not using a WithEvents variable - if you do, even with native events, you still use `witheventsvariablename_eventname`

Comment: Well...that's what got your code to work for me.

Comment: @Rory I think you may be right about the timing.. at least that seems the most logical.

Comment: probably can't raise one event inside another....Like the reason there is an `Activate()` **method** as well as `Activate()` **event** on for example `Worksheet` class...

Comment: Interesting question that was also well answered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on the VBA Language Specification section [5.3.1.10 Lifecycle Handler Declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199474.aspx), I would guess this is the reason (emphasis mine):

> If a class defines a Class_Initialize lifecycle handler, that subroutine will be invoked as an method each time an instance of that class is created by the New operator, by referencing a variable that was declared with an `<as-auto-object>` and whose current value is Nothing, or by call the CreateObject function (section 6.1.2.8.1.4) of the VBA Standard Library. The target object of the invocation is the newly created object. **The invocation occurs before a reference to the newly created object is returned from the operations that creates it.**

So in your case, in the line

`Set cFactory = New Factory`

The `Class_Initialize` method of `Factory` is run *before* the assignment is made, which means while the event IS raised, the `FactoryTest` class instance doesn't know about it.

---

**UPDATE**

I gave it a quick test by adding a method to `Factory` which calls the `Class_Initialize` function:

```
Public Sub test()
    Class_Initialize
End Sub
```

And then added a call to it as part of the `FactoryTest.Class_Initialize` method:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set cFactory = New Factory
    cFactory.test
End Sub
```

Since the call to the method `test` takes place after the `New Factory` has been assigned to `cFactory`, the "after initialized..." message displays as expected.

Comment: ++ I digged the docs for about half an hour and couldn't find it. Well done all clear now