# Multiple Listeners for VBA Custom Event

Tags: vba, events, ms-word

In VBA (for MS Word) is it possible to have multiple listeners for a custom Event?  I created a custom event as per: [Custom Event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589039/custom-event-not-firing) but what I really want is to have multiple listeners...

It seems logical that an event only fires for the instance that it relates to, but I want to trigger code several places when an event occurs... is it possible?

Modified code form above Ref:

FactoryTest calls Factory. Factory raises an event. FactoryTest Listens for Event and responds.

Add a new class module and name it Factory

```
Public Event AfterInitialize()
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

Public Sub test()
    RaiseEvent AfterInitialize
End Sub
```

Add another class module and name is FactoryTest

```
Private WithEvents cFactory As Factory

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set cFactory = New Factory
    cFactory.test
End Sub

Private Sub cFactory_AfterInitialize()
    Debug.Print "after inialized..."
End Sub
```

And add a standard Module with the code below

```
 Sub Main()

    Dim fTest As FactoryTest
    Set fTest = New FactoryTest

End Sub
```

Comment: So... in a nutshell... I want another class module called Factory2  that will be capable of using the SAME event as Factory uses...

Comment: Yes it is possible to have multiple listeners, simply create another class like ```FactoryTest``` where you declare and create instance of the class ```Factory``` and add event-handler the same way you already have it in class ```FactoryTest```. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Hi Dee - thank you for your comment.  I *think* I tried that and yes I can get FactoryTest2 to trap an event from Factory BUT so far each FactoryTestx is its own instance of Factory and I'm unable to get FactoryTest and FactoryTest2 to trap the same event.

Basically I want to raise a single event that all my FactoryTests will trap / respond to...  I hope that makes sense!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understand your problem correctly. If you need that all the `FactoryTests` respond to single event you'll probably have to pass the reference to one common `Factory` to all the `FactoryTests` instances and not create new one in each `FactoryTest`. HTH

> Standard module, here the common instance of `Factory` is created and two `FactoryTests` which both respond to the same event of `Factory`

```
Option Explicit

 Sub Main()
    Dim myFactory As Factory
    Set myFactory = New Factory

    Dim test1 As FactoryTest1
    Dim test2 As FactoryTest2

    Set test1 = New FactoryTest1
    Set test2 = New FactoryTest2

    Set test1.FactoryInstance = myFactory
    Set test2.FactoryInstance = myFactory

    myFactory.test
End Sub
```

> Factory test class module, create more of them where each receives reference to one common `Factory` instance

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents cFactory As Factory

Private Sub cFactory_AfterInitialize()
    Debug.Print "after inialized..." & VBA.TypeName(Me)
End Sub

Public Property Get FactoryInstance() As Factory
    Set FactoryInstance = cFactory
End Property

Public Property Set FactoryInstance(ByRef factoryObject As Factory)
    Set cFactory = factoryObject
End Property
```

> Output for two Factory test classes named `FactoryTest1` and `FactoryTest2`

```
after inialized...FactoryTest1
after inialized...FactoryTest2
```

Comment: Yes I think we're on the same page - I'll test that and get back to you, many thanks :-D